# Bottom Tab bar with selected item Zoom in android

Tags: android

I have to create a new design for **bottom bar** in an android app. But I Have no idea how to create this new Bottom Navigation Bar. Please see the link below:
[Bottom bar screenshot:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svmnu3b9rtyxwmn/3%20request%20-%20Copy.png?dl=0)
and **help me** out :(

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwnAV.png)

Comment: I tried to create it with custom layout. but its'nt working.. :(

Comment: Post your code in your question so people can review and ask you to improve it.

Comment: use selector and change images of `TabLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Use Selector on tab bar when your tab selected then change tab icon and text (Increase size of text and icon programmatically ) because android tabLayout not provide any zoom function